# Outliers for Normalization: Is it important?

Tags: outliers

I'm new to statistics and have to do some research analysis using SPSS. I need to know, what is the purpose of removing outliers? I want to normalize my set of data obtained through a national survey, but there are a few variables that do not show a bell curve even if I have transformed my data. log, ln, sqrt etc. I have tried everything. What else can be done? I have to do multiple regression analysis on the data to predict future data.

Comment: Multiple regression by ordinary-least squares assumes at most that the errors, & therefore (approximately) the residuals are independent normal random variables with zero mean & common variance. No assumptions are necessary about the distribution of the predictors, which indeed may be fixed at arbitrary values by an experimenter; or, it follows, about that of the response. So are you worrying about nothing?

Comment: like i said, im new to this, ive been forced to work on this so i need alot of help..thank u so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

What is an outlier, really?

Some outliers may arise from faulty data management; somebody input "5,000" when they really meant "5.000". If this is the case, outliers must be removed because they are *wrong*, i.e. have measurement error.

However, outliers can also have another meaning. Say that you have a sample of some variable X that seems to be standard normally distributed. However, in your dataset, you also have some very high/low, which seems less likely under the assumption of normality. In this case, some people are apt to ignore those very high/low values, which I personally think is incorrect - since they seem to be the most informative in terms of the real data-generating process (assuming we can exclude measurement error as the source of their values).

Comment: thank you so much for your reply, im so releived now because i didnot want to delete the outliers